# Could NOT find Boost (missing: python) on macOS

Tags: macos, boost, cmake, freecad

ERROR INF:

```
-- Could NOT find Boost (missing: python) (found version "1.71.0")
```

I've tried everything I found in here, and nothing works.

Here is what I've done:

1. Firstly, I've installed boost, boost_python and boost_python3 through brew install.
   However, I noticed that in boost dir there are "include" and "lib" dirs, but there is only "lib" in boost_python and boost_python3, which I don't understand.
2. Run cmake as below:

   CC=/usr/bin/gcc CXX=/usr/bin/g++ cmake 
   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"   
   -DBUILD_QT5=1                  
   -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/lib/cmake"  
   -DFREECAD_USE_EXTERNAL_KDL=1   
   -DBUILD_FEM_NETGEN=1           
   -DFREECAD_CREATE_MAC_APP=1     
   -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="./.."  
   -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$ANACONDA_HOME/lib/libpython3.7.so 
   -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$ANACONDA_HOME/include/python3.7 
   -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$ANACONDA_HOME/bin/python3.7 
   **-DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE:BOOL=ON** 
   **-DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=TRUE** 
   **-DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.71.0** 
   **-DBOOST_LIBRARY_DIRS=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.71.0/lib** 
   **-DBOOST_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.71.0/include** 
   ../

### But the log says:

> - Found Boost: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.71.0/include (found version "1.71.0")
> - Found PythonInterp: /bin/python3.7 (Required is at least version "3")
> - Found PythonLibs: /lib/libpython3.7.so (Required is at least version "3")
> - Detected Homebrew install at /usr/local
> - Found PythonInterp: /bin/python3.7
> - Found PythonLibs: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libpython.tbd
>   (found version "2.7.10")
> - Found Boost: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.71.0/include (found suitable version "1.71.0", minimum required is "1.48") found components:
>   filesystem program_options regex system thread chrono date_time atomic
>   **- Could NOT find Boost (missing: python) (found version "1.71.0")**

As you can see, there are some components in Boost except for python.

3. I've tried:

   -DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/boost_python3/1.71.0_1
   -DBOOST_LIBRARY_DIRS=/usr/local/Cellar/boost_python3/1.71.0_1/lib

But due to there's no "include" dir in boost_python3, I don't know how to edit BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR. Therefore, the log says:

> Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR)

**PLEASE HELP!!!!!!! I intend to compile FreeCAD on my mac but I've been stuck for a few days!**

Comment: Add `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` option to `cmake` and it will print exact files which are searched, and exact directories which are considered. Compare these files with ones you actually have.